# Haskell: min distance between neighbor numbers on a list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define a functino that finds the minimum distance between to neighbor numbers on a list

something like this:

```
minNeighborsDistance [2,3,6,2,0,1,9,8] => 1
```

My code looks like this:

```
minNeighborsDistance [] = []
minNeighborsDistance (x:xs) = minimum[minNeighborsDistance xs ++ [subtract x (head xs)]]
```

Although this seems to run, once I enter a list I receive an Exception error.

I'm new to Haskell I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: You are returning a list in the empty case...while your example returns a numeric value.  Did you mean to return 0, or `Nothing`?  It seems you would want to break this down with a "neighborsDistance" function to which you could apply minimum, maximum, etc.  (Perhaps `neighborsDistance [1 2 4] = Just [1 2]`, for instance, and `neighborsDistance [1] = Nothing`)  *(I'm just reading beginner Haskell questions at the moment, starting out...)*

Comment: Just another small tip: It is almost always more efficient to prepend an element to a list with `y :` rather than appending it with `++ [y]`, if you can use the former instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you pass a singleton list to `minNeighborsDistance` then

1. It'll fail to match `[]` in the first line, then
2. it'll successfully match `(x:xs)` assigning the single value to `x` and the empty like to `xs`, then
3. it'll throw an error when you try to access the `head` of an empty list.

Further, since you call `minNeighborsDistance` recursively then you'll always eventually call it on a singleton list excepting when you pass it an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with:

```
minDistance l = minimum . map abs . zipWith (-) l $ tail l
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
minDistance list = minimum (distance list)
  where
    distance list = map abs $ zipWith (-) list (tail list)
```

`distance` calculates the absolute value of the list being subtracted with itself shifted by 1 position:

```
  [2,3,6,2,0,1,9,8] -- the 8 is skipped but it does not make a difference
- [3,6,2,0,1,9,8]
= [1,3,4,2,1,8,1]
```

`minDistance` now just gets the smallest element of the resulting list.

Comment: You really don't need `right` when you are using `abs`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear (a type signature would really help here), but if you're wanting to calculate the difference between adjacent elements of the list, then find the minimum of those numbers, I would say the most clear way is to use some extra pattern matching:

```
-- Is this type you want the function to have?
minNeighborsDistance :: [Int] -> Int
minNeighborsDistance list = minimum $ go list
    where
        go (x:y:rest) = (x - y) : go (y:rest)
        go anythingElse = []        -- Or just go _ = []
```

However, this won't quite give you the answer you want, because the actual minimum for your example list would be `-4` when you go from `6` to `2`.  But this is an easy fix, just apply `abs`:

```
minNeighborsDistance :: [Int] -> Int
minNeighborsDistance list = minimum $ go list
    where
        go (x:y:rest) = abs (x - y) : go (y:rest)
        go anythingElse = []
```

I've used a helper function to calculate the differences from element to element, then the top-level definition calls `minimum` on that result to get the final answer.

There is an easier way, though, if you exploit a few functions in `Prelude`, namely `zipWith`, `map`, and `drop`:

```
minNeighborsDistance :: [Int] -> Int
minNeighborsDistance list
    = minimum        -- Calculates the minimum of all the distances
    $ (maxBound:)    -- Ensures we have at least 1 number to pass to
                     -- minimum by consing the maximum possible Int
    $ map abs        -- Ensure all differences are non-negative
    -- Compute the difference between each element.  I use "drop 1"
    -- instead of tail because it won't error on an empty list
    $ zipWith (-) list (drop 1 list)
```

So combined into one line without comments:

```
minNeighborsDistance list = minimum $ (maxBound:) $ map abs $ zipWith (-) list $ drop 1 list
```

Comment: I have a hunch you should drop that `(0:)` >:)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Why would that be?  It handles the case that `list` is a singleton list.  Without it `minNeighborsDistance [1]` raises an exception on an empty list.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ah, now I feel silly.  We could instead go with `maxBound` to get the behavior I _meant_ to have...