# Unpacking a Maybe on Lists describing Deltas (and is it a Good Idea in the First Place?)

Tags: haskell, option-type

As a newcomer to Haskell I'm reading StackOverflow top rated questions, new questions, etc. and today there was this one:

[Haskell: min distance between neighbor numbers on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976021/haskell-min-distance-between-neighbor-numbers-on-a-list)

I thought "well, I'll try that without looking at the answers".  For starters, I wrote:

```
neighborsDistance [] = []
neighborsDistance [a] = []
neighborsDistance (x:y:xs) = abs (x - y) : neighborsDistance (y:xs)
```

Then I could do `minimum neighborsDistance [2,3,6,2,0,1,9,8] => 1`.

But I didn't much care for how the edge cases worked, so I thought perhaps I'd try using Maybe.  I'd need a way to adapt the recursive rule to tolerate a "maybe" value so I looked on Hoogle at [Data.Maybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html) and found `fromMaybe`...which looked like it did what I wanted:

```
neighborsDistance [] = Nothing
neighborsDistance [a] = Just []
neighborsDistance (x:y:xs) = Just (abs (x - y) : fromMaybe [] neighborsDistance (y:xs))
```

But that gave me a `not in scope: fromMaybe` error.  Main question would be "why didn't that work?"

Another question is just generally about Haskell mindsets when looking at something like this.  Is this a bad use of Maybe?  Why does `head` throw an exception when called on an empty list vs return a Maybe type?

The question I got the problem from was trying to unify distance calculation with the minimum operation.  I'm assuming that you can break it out like this without losing significant efficiency (such that it will compose with minimum, or maximum, or whatever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that gave me a not in scope: fromMaybe error. Main question would be "why didn't that work?"

You need to `import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)` at the top of your file.

The Prelude itself does do an `import Data.Maybe` to get the definitions of `Maybe`, `Just`, and `Nothing`.  But it [does the import inside a module 'where' clause](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Prelude.html), and exports only those three definitions.  So the less common functions have to be manually imported.

> Is this a bad use of Maybe? Why does head throw an exception when called on an empty list vs return a Maybe type?

Usage of `head` is generally regarded as non-ideal. The [`Safe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.7/docs/Safe.html) package provides `headMay`, which does return a `Maybe`.

On the other hand, I think returning a `Maybe [Int]` is unnecessary here. The empty list already encodes the idea of there being no valid result. In fact, it's used commonly enough as a `Maybe` that we have [`maybeToList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybeToList) and [`listToMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe). Wrapping it in a `Maybe` means you need to spend more effort 'unwrapping' the value.

> I'm assuming that you can break it out like this without losing significant efficiency (such that it will compose with minimum, or maximum, or whatever)?

In most cases, yes. Haskell has [short-cut fusion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion).

Comment: Works, but how was I using Maybe and its constructors before if it wasn't included?  RE: why do this - An issue of invariant bothers me; that the list has a different number of elements than the input is a little irregular when I think of code that may be using it.  (Perhaps it should be the same length and put a Nothing at the beginning or end?)  But if you can't even say something like "The output list has one fewer entry than the input if there is a result" it seems dodgy.

Comment: `Maybe` is automatically included as part of the `Prelude`, the library that is included by default in all Haskell programs. The less common functions have to be manually imported though.

You actually can't (easily) say "the output list has one fewer entry than the input" in vanilla Haskell; that would require numbers to be types instead of values (though there are type system extensions for this, or you could use Peano numbers, but that's complicated too.)

Comment: Found a source sample of the [Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Prelude.html) *(I don't know anything about what version that is)* which has an `import Data.Maybe`, but I gather it is importing it and then only exporting the type and constructors?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what the Prelude is doing.

Comment: In practice, most code doesn't need to care exactly how many elements are in the list; usually you operate on the list as a collection, doing `map`s, `concat`s, and the like, that don't care if the list is empty or not.

Comment: Ok, got it...thanks.  Edited in the answer I was looking for, edit again if you'd prefer to say it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You main question can be answered in one line, you are probably missing:

```
import Data.Maybe
```

But why the whole stress with using a Maybe value? Because this problem has a clear answer for any list of length >= 2, you do not need to use a maybe type. A maybe type is generally only used when it is not sure whether the function will return a result or not, such as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908894/haskell-program-to-find-a-sub-string-within-a-string) case.

> Another question is just generally about Haskell mindsets when looking at something like this. Is this a bad use of Maybe? Why does head throw an exception when called on an empty list vs return a Maybe type?

Think about it: If you had a safe head which is implemented as the `listToMaybe` function in the [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html) package, you would have to handle the empty case too which is not what head is intended to do (which is extract the first element of a list).

For further information about `head` and empty lists, you should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364409/why-does-haskells-head-crash-on-an-empty-list-or-why-doesnt-it-return-an) as it already has been discussed.

> I'm assuming that you can break it out like this without losing significant efficiency (such that it will compose with minimum, or maximum, or whatever)?

Yes you can do that in Haskell, its pretty neat. As a hint: the `($)` and `(.)` operators are you best friends regarding this.